# Can apache run a python script which is NOT executable?

Tags: python, apache, webserver, chmod, ubuntu-18.04

I setup Ubuntu server 18.04 LTS, LAMP, and mod_mono (which appears to be working fine alongside PHP now by the way.) Got python working too; at first it gave an HTTP "Internal Server Error" message. `sudo chmod +x myfile.py` fixed this error and the code python generates is displayed fine. But any time the execute permission is removed from the file (such as by uploading a new version of the file), the execute bit is stripped and it breaks again.

A work-around was implemented with incrontab, where the cgi-bin folder was monitored for changes and any new writes caused `chmod +x %f` to be ran on them. This worked for awhile, then stopped, and seems a hokey solution at best. Perl, PHP, even ASPX do not need to be marked executable - only python.

**Is there any way Apache can "run" python *without* the file marked as executable?**

Answer (score 1):

The reason PHP works, is because the interpreter is loaded into Apache.  So Apache interprets the code.

For your Python, it runs as a CGI, so the interpreter is outside of Apache.

In your Python script, you probably have a `#!/usr/bin/python` first line (or something similar).  This tells the script to run using this interpreter.  This requires executable permission on the `.py` file, and allows you to call `myfile.py` directectly.

Instead run it like this: `/usr/bin/python myfile.py`.  This way the interpreter is the executable, and it will run myfile.py as the code.

---

Examples

- You want to run the py file "alone":

  ```
  file.py
      #!/usr/bin/python
      print("Hello")

  Running it:
      ./file.py
  ```
- You want to run it via the python executable, like you want via Apache:

  ```
  file.py
      print("Hello")

  Running it:
      /usr/bin/python file.py
  ```

Comment: I tried all manner of this up to `#!/usr/bin/python3.6 /var/www/html/myfile.py` but apache still returns `500 Internal Server Error`. It works if execute is set. Ideas?

Comment: Do not put the `#!` when calling it from the command line.  The `#!` should only be put on the first line of the py file when you want to execute it directly.  I edited my answer with examples.

Comment: Thanks for continuing with this. Well the command is the issue, the association of cgi-scripts to .py files in the Apache config is very concise and delineated, undoubtedly for security reasons. I can't see a way to have apache spawn `python myfile.py`.  It intrinsically *runs* the .py file, `./myfile.py` which is why it must be marked executable.  I did figure out one work-around however, which I'll share as an answer for others, but I bet there is some other, better way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Apache is capable of serving executed python scripts without the execute bit set on the .py file.

But here is a work-around: simply leave that file marked executable, but `import` a second python file. That *second file* does not need to be marked executable.

myfile.py (marked as executable and read-only - use this with apache):

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# enable debugging
# helper to run the other, non-executable file
# do not add .py to the import "filename"
import myfile2
```

myfile**2**.py (marked RW only, edit this file freely):

```
# this is the code which can change frequently
# and does not need to be marked executable...
print("Content-type: text/html\n\n")
print("<html><head><title>Python</title></head>")
print("<body>Hello, World!</body></html>")
```